# How can i retrieve a image from Parse.com via query at iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com for retrieving my data.I want to retrieve my images from parse via pf query but my approach does not working.I get nothing where my UIImageView is. Here is my code:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class"];
        [query whereKey:@"Yes or No" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


            if (!error) {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);



                for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++) {

                    object = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

                    NSString *Property1 = [object objectForKey:@"Property1"];

                    __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];


                    PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"Resimler"];
                    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
                        if (!error) {
                         MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                        }
                    }];

aClass *AC = [[aClass alloc]initWithProperty:Propert1 Picture:MyPicture];
                    [self.MyArray addObject:AC];



  }

            }


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }


    }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MyViewViewCell *cell = (MyViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    aClass *mC = [self.MyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.Label.text = mC.Property;

    cell.myImage.image = mC.Picture;
    return cell;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
At aClass.h
@interface aClass : NSObject
@property(strong)NSString *Property;

@property(strong)UIImage *Resim;

-(id)initWithProperty:(NSString *)aProperty Picture:(UIImage *)aPicture ;
@end

at aClass.m


@implementation Mekan
@synthesize Property, Picture;

-(id)initWithMekanIsmi:(NSString *)aProperty Picture:(UIImage *)aPicture{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        self.Property = aProperty;
        self.Picture = aPicture;
    }
    return self;

}
@end
```

I know it is kind of a mass code but i have to write those codes to illustrate where i assign myImage. So you can ask where you do not understand

Comment: I don't see in your code where you are assigning your UIImageView.

Comment: Consider adding something like `NSLog(@"No Error");` right above where you assign `MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];` to make sure that is firing.

Comment: i get no error message at NSLog, i will try to add where i assign UIImageView.

Comment: There's an error here: `aClass *mC = [self.MyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.Label.text = m1.Property;

    cell.myImage.image = m1.Picture;` You named your `aClass` instance mC, but then reference it as m1

Comment: it is a copy paste error, in actual code they are fit. sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"default.png"];
[userIcon getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
  imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    // update progress
}];
```

You seem to be assigning it to a UIImage properly, but never setting that image as the image for a UIImageView.

Comment: Your code is really hard to follow because you are using all these custom classes that I have no idea what they are. It appears your `aClass` is function like a dictionary and then being stuck into an array. I would move `aClass *AC = [[aClass alloc]initWithProperty:Propert1 Picture:MyPicture];
                    [self.MyArray addObject:AC];` into the `if (!error)` block and then do an `NSLog(@"%@", self.MyArray);` to make sure it is adding each one to start.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion. Before implement that  `cell.Label.text = mC.Property;` was working fine but after implement your suggestion it starts to not working. So the error must be in that if statement. But the strange thing is i can see no error message when i write nslog:@"no errro" in that if statement.

Comment: You aren't retrieving from Parse properly then it sounds. Try logging the error in `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` by putting this right after your `if (!error){}else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }`

Comment: i just added aClass's header file and implementation file for make clearer question.